# Having a UITextField alter a Webview URL

Tags: ios, xcode, url, uiwebview, uitextfield

I have a viewcontroller with with a xib file. The file needs to have a TextField and a Button that leads to another viewcontroller with a web view. I want to have the URL be altered by whatever the user enters into the text field. So for example:

URL in WebView: http://www.google.com/
**user enter football into text field**
New Url in WebView: http://www.google.com/football

Any help would really be appreciated i already have my "main page" leading to a webview i just need to know what code needs to go were to alter the url.

Thanks in advance. If code is need i can post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use string literals to pass the text of the box to the webview.  Like this:

```
NSString *stringToPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.google.com/%@", self.textField.text];
```

Then, use a custom init method to pass your string to the new view:

```
self.viewController = [ViewController alloc]initWithAddress:stringToPass];
```

Make sure to declare `-(id)initWithAddress:(NSString*)address;` in the .h.

Answer (score 0):

To carry on @CodaFi...

```
// WebViewController.m

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *url;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView;

//@synthesize, etc.

-(id)initWithAddress:(NSString*)address {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.url = [NSURL urlWithString:address];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: could you guys elaborate a little bit more. im very new to this